# How to play simple notes like a ding-dang sound in terminal

Tags: shell-script, terminal, audio, bell

I have written a few scripts to be run under a `bash` environment. I would like to play a sound after certain commands are executed or results are ready. This could be something like a chime, a bell or a single tick-tack but it is not my system and I do not have any idea what their system configurations are and what their hardware or software might be. So I can not run it through a player or you say .wav file. Is there any option to play two notes like A and F#? If this is not possible what is the closest option?
Thanks

Comment: Can you better define "certain times"? At-exit-of-program is usually as simple as `that-long-running-command; some-script-that-makes-noise-or-sends-mail-or-both`

Answer (score 5):

That's not how terminals work.

Terminal sessions are pure byte streams so all you can send to terminals are the ASCII control characters that make the terminal take special actions (like `BS`=Move cursor back one space) and the terminal emulation control sequences (almost always a VT100 variant these days) that make the terminal take special actions (like clear the screen or set/clear reverse video). The only one of these that will be of interest to you here is the ASCII control character `BEL`, code point 7, which is meant to invoke the terminal bell. But what it does is totally up to the user's terminal software. It might play a (fixed) sound, flash the screen (visual bell), something else, or nothing at all.